# Lookup field converting text to numeric value

Tags: lookup-column

I have a Library with documents that I need to index: File X has attributes such as first name, last name, location, ID, etc. I added a lookup field so when I enter in a last name, it will look on my list (which is on the same SharePoint site) and return first name, location, ID, etc.  My ID is stored on the list as a single line of text.  However, when I pull over the info to add index fields to my document, it converts my ID field from a text field to a numeric one creating an exponential mess of a number.  How can I force a lookup field to return text and not convert to a number?